# How to read all folder name from a folder in laravel?

Tags: laravel, directory

I am developig a website using laravel. here i need to upload photos in different folder chossed by user. Here i think i need to know all the folder names inside image folder. Is there any way in laravel to read all folder names inside image folder.

Comment: you can use PHP scandir() Function 
refer https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_scandir.asp

Comment: Thanks Shankar S Bavan.
It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have done that.

```
$foler_names = [];
$i = 0;
$dir = public_path().'/img/gallery_img/';

$dirList = scandir($dir);

foreach ($dirList as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($value, '.') !== false) {
    }else {
      $foler_names[$i] = $value;
       echo $value;
       echo '</br>';
      $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: great that you did it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Storage` facade for it.

```
$directories = Storage::directories($directory);

// Recursive...
$directories = Storage::allDirectories($directory);
```

Check the details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#directories